# CSS Float:Left Issues

Tags: css

I am having a weird issue with CSS that will has to be simple to fix, but I'm still learning CSS so I need some help.  As you can see from the link, the float div on the left `area_left` affects the div on the right `blog_area_right`.

http://www.brockpatterson.com/secret.php

Thanks in advance,
Drummer392

Comment: *the float div on the left affects the div on the right.* - which would that be?

Comment: can you please explain a bit more? which left fiv affects which right div? and affects how?

Comment: I agree with @Joseph. What part of the website is `the float div on the left affects the div on the right.`?

Comment: So div on the left `area_left` div affects the div on the right `blog_area_right`.  The left div pushes the content of the right div down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give float to your `blog_area_right` DIV & remove `margin-left`. Write like this:

```
#blog_area_right {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 9px 15px #00A5D1;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 290px;
```

}

Comment: perfect.  I really am terrible when it comes to troubleshooting things like this, but I learn something new everyday!